# Haskell: changing type alias to newtype yields error

Tags: haskell, newtype

In my library I want to expose the name of the underlying monadic state to the user in the documentation, but I don't want them to be able to tear it apart -- I want to make a black box.

So, I started with fully working code using the following type alias:

```
type Surge e c z m = ErrorT (Failure z) (ReaderT (SurgeChan e c) (Parser' ByteString m))
```

Then, in order to make it more robust I changed it into a `newtype` and enabled `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`:

```
newtype Surge e c z m a = Surge
    { runSurge' :: ErrorT (Failure z) (ReaderT (SurgeChan e c) (Parser' ByteString m)) a }
    deriving (Monad, Applicative, Functor)
```

I had some other code which needed to be adjusted like so:

```
res <- flip St.evalStateT prod . flip runReaderT sc . runErrorT $ pipeline
```

==>

```
res <- flip St.evalStateT prod . flip runReaderT sc . runErrorT . runSurge' $ pipeline
```

Unfortunately, for some reason not all the code would typecheck after I made the `type`->`newtype` change. This part of the code in-particular:

```
{-# INLINE decodeAndHandlePacket #-}
decodeAndHandlePacket
    = handlePacket ~< errorP (lift.lift.liftM (first DecodeFailure) . decodeGet $ decodePacket)
```

... now fails to typecheck with quite a long error, whereas it had not before:

```
src/Surge/Internal.hs:101:27:
    Couldn't match type ‘ErrorT
                           (Failure z0) (t0 (St.StateT (Producer ByteString m0 x0) m0))’
                  with ‘Surge e c z m’
    Expected type: Proxy a' a () p' (Surge e c z m) ByteString
      Actual type: Proxy
                     a'
                     a
                     ()
                     p'
                     (ErrorT
                        (Failure z0) (t0 (St.StateT (Producer ByteString m0 x0) m0)))
                     ByteString
    Relevant bindings include
      decodeAndHandlePacket :: Proxy a' a () p' (Surge e c z m) ()
        (bound at src/Surge/Internal.hs:100:5)
      handleCommand :: Handler c p' (Surge e c z m)
        (bound at src/Surge/Internal.hs:84:7)
      handleEvent :: Handler e p' (Surge e c z m)
        (bound at src/Surge/Internal.hs:84:7)
      handlePacket :: Handler ByteString p' (Surge e c z m)
        (bound at src/Surge/Internal.hs:84:7)
      stage :: Stage ByteString p' e c (Surge e c z m)
               -> Producer ByteString (Surge e c z m) ()
        (bound at src/Surge/Internal.hs:84:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(~<)’, namely
      ‘errorP
         (lift . lift . liftM (first DecodeFailure) . decodeGet
          $ decodePacket)’
    In the expression:
      handlePacket
      ~<
        errorP
          (lift . lift . liftM (first DecodeFailure) . decodeGet
           $ decodePacket)
```

I have no idea what to do. Both sides look identical to me.

Full code available at http://lpaste.net/109472 . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
decodeAndHandlePacket
        = handlePacket ~< hoist Surge (errorP (lift.lift.liftM (first DecodeFailure) . decodeGet $ decodePacket))
```

Note that the return type of the call to `errorP` is

```
Proxy a'0 a0 () p' (ErrorT (Failure ...)) ByteString
```

and you want to replace the fifth parameter with the newtype, i.e.

```
Proxy a'0 a0 () p' (Surge e c z m) ByteString
```

This newtype is a monad (a type constructor) and you need to "`hoist`" the action in the `(ErrorT (Failure ...))` into the `(Surge ...)` monad.

Answer (score 3):

`decodeAndHandlePacket` expects to deal with a `Surge e c z m` but you are giving it an `(ErrorT (Failure z0) (t0 (St.StateT (Producer ByteString m0 x0) m0)))`, i.e. you are not wrapping it with the `Surge` constructor. When you wrap a type with a newtype wrapper, you have to make sure you perform the wrapping and unwrapping everywhere.

Comment: Naively I tried `... ~< Surge (errorP ...)` but that didn't work. Where should I insert the constructor?

Comment: wrap another `(`, `)` pair around it (I think)

Comment: Nope, you get `Couldn't match expected type ‘Proxy a' a () p' (Surge e c z m) ByteString’ with actual type ‘Surge e0 c0 z0 m0 a0’`, which looks to me like it doesn't belong there.